# How to enable infinite scrolling with masonry?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, fluid-layout

So how do I add or integrate infinite scrolling with my masonry fluid layout? I have already googled but don't understand.Here is what I got so far:

```
/**
 * Base js functions
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('.container');

    var gutter = 20;
    var min_width = 270;
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.box',
            gutterWidth: gutter,
            isAnimated: true,
              columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                var box_width = (((containerWidth - 2*gutter)/3) | 0) ;

                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = (((containerWidth - gutter)/2) | 0);
                }

                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = containerWidth;
                }

                $('.box').width(box_width);

                return box_width;
              }
        });
    });
});
```

Can someone help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the source code for the infinite scroll example on the [masonry site](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html) you can see the function that does all the work after the initial Masonry setup. After your $container.imagesLoaded function, add in the Infinite Scroll configs and then trigger Masonry in a callback function. Also, be sure to include jquery.infinitescroll.min.js after jquery.masonry.min.js.

Here's the JS from that page:

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth: 100
  });
});

// Infinite Scroll
$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
  }
);
```

});